# AWS Endpoints: why doesn't AWS enable S3 endpoint by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

If an AWS account enabled S3 endpoint, when EC2 is trying to download a file from an S3 bucket owned by you, ec2 will go to the S3 bucket within the AWS infrastructure, instead of going through the Internet Gateway.

It must save unnecessary traffic and improve the performance of downloading. why doesn't AWS enable it for EC2 instance by default?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because AWS is trying to make you consciously make the decision, after all they are giving you the tools to configure the network how you would like to use it.

As you rightly point out it saves on bandwidth and improves performance but does add extra overhead in terms of management of configuration. Additionally this feature has not always existed, by forcing it on people it could add extra confusion. Generally AWS does not enable new features by default and instead keeps functionality as it was as launch.

Comment: *"As you rightly point out it saves on bandwidth and improves performance"*  It saves on bandwidth costs compared to running though a NAT Gateway but not for instances with public/EIP using only an Internet Gateway, where S3 bandwidth within the region is already free.  Also, there's no reason I can think of to believe that a VPC endpoint has any performance advantage (or disadvantage) over either a NAT Gateway or public/EIP+IGW.

Comment: Hi Michael by proving a private connection to AWS, surely it improves on both latency as well as providing a more reliable connection? :)

Comment: There is no actual private connection created, it's all virtual.  [*"An Amazon VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3 is a logical entity within a VPC that allows connectivity only to S3."*](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/) Note the phrase "logical entity."  There isn't any reason to believe that there's any meaningful performance difference between using one of these and using an Internet Gateway or a NAT Gateway, to access S3.  NAT Gateways and Internet Gateways are also logical entities -- smoke and mirrors provided by the network infrastructure.